# Horizontal scroll bar for iframe with content that has overflow-x: hidden

Tags: html, css, iframe, scrollbar

I am working on a landing page with width 760px and need to have an iframe with content (a flash demo) that is 980px wide. So I would need to have a horizontal scrollbar in order to view the entire content. However, no matter what I add as scrolling attributes (e.g. scrolling="auto/yes" etc), nothing happens - no horizontal scrollbar at all.

The page displayed in the iframe has the following command in the source code:

```
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

As far as I understand it, this is the reason why there is no horizontal scrollbar in my iframe. Is there any workaround for that to get one?

Comment: Can you share more code or a live link?

Comment: This is the code I have in my HTML (cannot display the source for the iframe at the moment): 
`<div id="one">
    <iframe src="xyz.com" scrolling="auto"  overflow-x: scroll; width="981" height="620"></iframe>
  </div>`

CSS:
`div.one {width: 760px; float: left; vertical-align: bottom; }`

Comment: Do you have control over the iFrames contents?

Comment: no, unfortunately not

Comment: added a new answer to do it via javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap the `iframe` in a containing `div`, applying the fixed-width to the container.

-

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

-

### CSS

```
.container {
    width: 980px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: the iframe already is in a div with correct fixed-width. No result, whatsoever...

Comment: @dtr because you probably haven't set the correct overflow properties of the container. It works for me well.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the iFrames (body/child) overflow with javascript.

Something like:

```
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById(one).setStyles({ 'overflow': 'auto' });
};
```

maybe this, not sure which will get the body of the iframes contant:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var frame = document.getElementById('one'),
    frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
    frameDoc.setStyles({ 'overflow': 'auto' });
};
```

Comment: You will have cross domain issues with this code. You're not allowed to change styles on cross domain iFrames.

Comment: @gugateider all answers would have CORS limitations. But I don't think that is the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Mention the width and height in to the iframe

and add `overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:scroll` in the style of iframe

```
<iframe width="300" height="315" src="http://webstarts.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:scroll;"></iframe>
```

here is the [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/5BWfX/)

Comment: tried that but it does not help. It looks/feels as if the horizontal is just "suppressed" by the code on the source page. Vertical scrollbar reacts to all scrolling commands.

Answer (score 0):

Following Sergio's answer here is what I did when I found myself with the same problem, using jQuery:

- Take the iframe
- Search for the body
- Apply a different overflow property

`$('#iframe').contents().find('body').css('overflow', 'auto');`

All this once the page has been completely loaded, of course:

`$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Now it displays the scrollbars as I expected

Answer (score 0):

You should use overflow-x: visible.
If your content is hosted elsewhere you will not be able to change due to cross domain issues.

Imagine if you own a website and someone else wants to iFrame your website and make changes to it ( if you could change the overflow, you could literally change any styling and that would be a huge security leak ). That is the reason why you can't.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS-rule for "body", no "width" is specified. If I understand it correctly if there is no width then such content can not overflow anything horizontally. It can not be "wider" than anything because it has no "width", so it can not overflow it either.

So I would try giving a width-attribute to the body of the document displayed inside the iFrame.

Naturally this might work in some browsers but not in others.